# How many matrices are there in the vector space $M_{m\times n} \mathbb (Z_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The answer is given to be $2^{mn}$. I know that $\mathbb Z_2$ has 2 elements but I don't get how we're arriving at this solution. Is the number of matrices related to dimension or something?

Comment: dimension of the space is $mn$

Comment: Is it dependent on the dimension?

Comment: How many $1 \times 2 $ matrices are in the space? $[1,0]$ ,$[0,0]$,$[0,1]$,$[1,1]$ and with how many matrices as a base can you generate them ? with only $[1,0]$ and $[0,1]$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** How many values can each entry of the matrix take? How many values does the matrix have?

Comment: Each entry of the matrix can take 2 values. A matrix has $m\times n$ entries. So shouldn't it be $2\times m\times n$?

Comment: Not quite. Let's take an example of just a $2\times 2$ matrix. Each of the $4$ entries can take $2$ possible values - so there are $2\times2\times2\times 2$ possibilities. Can you see how to generalise this for an $m \times n$ matrix?

Answer (score 4):

In a matrix $m\times n$ you have $mn$ entries. For each entry you can choose two possible value: 0 or 1. So you can have $2^{mn}$ possible different matrices.